# Duplicate jquery on add and removeclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using addClase and removeClass like this:

```
$('.myBar').removeClass('number1');
$('.myBar').addClass('number2');
```

But this gives a error: "Duplicated jQuery selector".

Is this bad and do I have to chance something or do I just ignore it?

Btw, this is my first time working with jQuery so i'm just playing around with it.

Comment: Please add the coresponding HTML

Comment: There is no such jquery error as "Duplicated jQuery selector" you must have some other tool that produces this

Comment: @Liam With all respect, the problem in link you have provided as a duplicate is kinda more complex. This one is simple, with a simple answer.

Comment: It's really not, `var bar = $('.myBar')`, [exactly what it says in the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21411299/542251)

Comment: Oh I couldn't find that topic, thanks guys.
The  answer below worked for me and is easy to understand so that's what I'm using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeClass` and `addClass` functions in one line to avoid duplicating the selector.

```js
$('.myBar').removeClass('number1').addClass('number2');
```

```css
.number1 {
  color: red;
}

.number2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='myBar number1'>Text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me